# Passing attribute value to array of "this" element when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

What is the easiest way to push element attribute value to an array from the following function, I am pushing the values if all elements are checked from the tree, also from a closest ul list, but can not get the last children ul, basically i have a 3 levels nested ul, and I need to get the attr value of last ul li when you check any of the elements from that list.

I have the a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0g1hk7mt/3/

and this is how the js looks like:

```
var arr = [];  
  function checkboxGroup() {

      $('#sidebarNav input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        arr = [];      
        var checkboxes = $(this).parent().next('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]');

          //console.log(checkboxes);
        //[10101, 191919, 19191, 119191]

        if ($(this)[0].checked == true) {
          checkboxes.each(function(){
              arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
              $(this).prop('checked', true).attr('checked', 'checked');
          });
        } else {
          checkboxes.each(function(){
              $(this).prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
              //console.log(this);
          });
        };
       alert(arr);
      });

    } 
  checkboxGroup()
```

Comment: Can you please attached the HTML as well?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with js/html http://jsfiddle.net/0g1hk7mt/1/ @rgrano

Comment: Some note on your markup in the fiddle: `<li>` is the only valid direct descendent of `<ul>`, so wrapping your `<li>` in a `<div>` is invalid markup. Also, do clean up your markup and indent properly — it's difficult to see what structure you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have 'div ul li span label checkbox', I was missing the parent ul tag, I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0g1hk7mt/3/

Comment: What's `json` got to do with this?

Comment: is it a bad markup @j08691 ?

Comment: No I'm asking why the question was tagged with `json`. I don't see how it applies.

Comment: Actually the ul tree was generated by a json file, I'll remove the tag from this question, since the topic is not related to json.